# Assigning an entire array with a single statement

Tags: c

Let us say that I declare and initialize

```
int a[3] = {1, 2, 3};
```

How can I later asisgn the entire array in one fell swoop? i.e.

```
a = {3, 2, 1};
```

Comment: You can't use that initialization form after declaration, unfortunately.

Comment: +1 For "one fell swoop". Have you been reading LOTR? :)

Comment: @muntoo: What does LOTR have to do with this typical English phrase?

Comment: @TomalakGeret'kal Well, that's where I first saw it.

Comment: @muntoo: I think I first saw "well" in a book called "Suzie Squawk" at the age of 3. You must be reading it too!

Comment: @TomalakGeret'kal [Your days are numbered.](http://xkcd.com/169/)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If your c compiler supports compound literals, you can use `memcpy`:

```
memcpy(a, (int[]){3, 2, 1}, sizeof a);
```

If you don't plan to stick any variables in there (you can; isn't C99 amazing?), `(int[])` can be replaced by `(const int[])` to put the literal into static memory.

Comment: +1, but maybe it's worth noting at least which compiler supports it.

Comment: Any C99 compiler supports this. MSVC, unfortunately is C89

Comment: Are you sure there is such a notion as "C99 compiler"? Even gcc hasn't yet implemented C99 till to the end. As for reasons why it is not in MSVC you can find them in this interview: http://drdobbs.com/cpp/231900562

Comment: Just as an additional remark, it would be a good habit to always qualify such compound literals as `const`, e.g `(int const[]){ 3, 2, 1}` since the compiler is then allowed to place this in static memory.

Answer (score 4):

compound literal is part of ANSI C (C99). Since it is part of the language, any compiler claiming to be conforming to C99 must support this:

memcpy(a, (int[]){3, 2, 1}, sizeof a);

gcc can be invoked as "gcc -Wall -W -std=c99 -pedantic" to specify the standard.

Since it is more than 11 years since C99, I think it's safe and probably a good idea to start using the new capabilities the language provides.

compound literals are discussed in section 6.5.2.5 of [n869.txt](http://people.freebsd.org/~green/c9x-draft.txt)

Answer (score 3):

You can't; you'll need to use something like `memset` if the values are all the same (and each element is a byte big), or a simple for-loop if they're not a byte big and if the numbers can be calculated. If the values cannot be calculated at runtime, you'll need to do each one by hand like `a[x] = y;`.

The reason they are called "initialiser lists" is because they can be used to *initialise* something, and initialisation by definition only happens once.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do that. An array can only be *initialized* from a brace expression in a declarator-initializer. You assign arrays.

In C89 there wasn't even such a thing as a "temporary array", though as of C99 these exist by virtue of [compound literals](http://drdobbs.com/184401404) (see @Dave's answer).

Comment: wrong for the part of "there is no such thing as temporary array". See Dave's answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a non-portable way of doing it that, strictly speaking, can also involve undefined behavior:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
  int a[3] = { 1, 2, 3 };
  printf("%d,%d,%d\n", a[0], a[1], a[2]);
  // assuming ints are 4-bytes-long, bytes are 8-bit-long and
  // the byte order in ints is from LSB to MSB (little-endian):
  memcpy(a, "\x03\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00", sizeof(a));
  printf("%d,%d,%d\n", a[0], a[1], a[2]);
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
1,2,3
3,2,1
```

Comment: Can? Or will? It's one or the other, surely.