# Lvalues, Rvalues and Array Initialisation in C

Tags: c, arrays, unit-testing, pointers, rvalue

Being able to define an array e.g.

```
int a[] = {1,2,3};
```

is very convenient, however, the array a is an r-value so I can't subsequently change the values in a, e.g.

```
a[] = {4,5,6};
```

The context for wanting to do this is writing a bunch of unit tests where I am feeding in arrays to functions and testing the outputs. I'm running tests on the same function with different inputs and would like to avoid having to have unique names for my input arrays, e.g. I'm having to do this:

```
int test1_a[] = {1,2,3};
/* calls to functions */

int test2_a[] = {4,5,6};
/* calls to functions */
```

Also, if I want to pass a pointer to an array into a function I have to 1st cast it like this:

```
int a[] = {1,2,3};
int *b = a;

my_func(&b);
```

passing a pointer to an r-value like this doesn't work:

```
my_func(&a);
```

My question is whether there is any other way to easily initialise an array of values without suffering from these limitations? (particularly with a view to making it easy to write many similar unit tests without each test having a unique set of array names)

Comment: This might be related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8380348/726361

Comment: If your only problem is reinitialising the array without recompiling, then you could read it from a file or from a database. (dont forget the size!).

Comment: good point - i think that may be the way to go. I'm moving from python back to C at the moment hence all these (possibly) silly questions on the basics...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already have the values you want to pass to the functions, why not use a multi-dimensional array?

```
int a[][] = {
    { 1, 2, 3 },
    { 4, 5, 6 }
}

for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
{
    /* Call functions with 'a[i]' as argument */
}
```

Also, if the functions you call expect an array, and you have a e.g. `int a[] = {...}; int *b = a;`, then don't call them with `&b`. Using `&b` passes the address of the *pointer*, not what it points to.

Comment: nice suggestion, that looks like a tidy solution. I think the memcpy route just confuses things further and introduces potential portability issues. I'll leave that one alone.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one option:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

void ReinitArray(int* p, size_t cnt, ...)
{
  va_list ap;

  va_start(ap, cnt);

  while (cnt--)
  {
    *p++ = va_arg(ap, int);
  }

  va_end(ap);
}

int array[5] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

int main(void)
{
  size_t i;

  printf("array[5]=");
  for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) printf("%d ", array[i]);
  printf("\n");

  ReinitArray(array, 5, 11, 22, 33, 44, 55);

  printf("array[5]=");
  for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) printf("%d ", array[i]);
  printf("\n");

  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
array[5]=1 2 3 4 5
array[5]=11 22 33 44 55
```

And you can simply write `my_func(a);` where `a` is an array name. This will be equivalent to passing `&a[0]`, the address of the very first array element. You can't pass entire arrays directly as function parameters in C.

Answer (score 1):

If i have understood your question properly.I guess the following should solve your problem.

```
memcpy(a, (int[]){3, 2, 1}, sizeof a);
```

Only if your c compiler supports compound literals(c99 onwards).

To specify the standard, gcc can be invoked as "gcc -std=c99 -Wall -pedantic".