# Why do we need to initialize or declare two dimensions simultaneously and not one after another in c

Tags: c

```
int a[3][3] = { {1, 2, 3} , {4, 5, 6} , {7, 8, 9} };
```

Is working

```
int a[3][3] ;
a[3][3] = { {1, 2, 3} , {4, 5, 6} , {7, 8, 9}
```

Is not working . It shows and error in my gcc compiler

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first line of code is declaring the array and defining *the entire contents*. What you're saying here is "create a 3x3 array of integers with these contents."

When you write:

```
int a[3][3];
```

What you're saying is, "create a 3x3 array of integers." You're not specifying the contents.

Your second example has two problems.

First, arrays are 0-based, so `a[3][3]` doesn't exist. The valid indexes are 0, 1, and 2.

More importantly, when you address `a[x][y]`, you're addressing *that specific cell*. In other words, "assign a value to cell [2][2] in the array."

So `a[2][2] = 42;` is valid. But you can't assign an array to `a[2][2]` because it only holds one integer.

Comment: For completeness, can you assign an entire array to `a` after declaration? ie `a = { /*...*/ };`?

Comment: @JamesThorpe: I honestly don't remember. It's been a long time since I worked in C. Why don't you give it a try?

Comment: I may do later - I don't work in C either, just happened across this question and am now wondering!

Comment: Nope, [doesn't work](http://ideone.com/GKictz).  [There's a workaround](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8380348/assigning-an-entire-array-with-a-single-statement) with memcpy